# tensorflow.keras during fit - Invalid argument Input to reshape is a tensor with 983040 values, but the requested shape has 1966080

Tags: keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0

How do I fix this error that I get, when I fit `tensorflow.keras.Model`, like:

```
history_model_2 = model.fit(train_data.next_batch(),
                            validation_data=validation_data.next_batch(),
                            epochs=32)
```

this is the error I get:

```
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 983040 values, but the requested shape has 1966080
     [[node model_2/reshape/Reshape (defined at <ipython-input-82-15c7d8d22e71>:10) ]]
     [[model_2/ctc/Cast_3/_90]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  Input to reshape is a tensor with 983040 values, but the requested shape has 1966080
     [[node model_2/reshape/Reshape (defined at <ipython-input-82-15c7d8d22e71>:10) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_33412]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function
```

*{{ in my `model.fit()`, `train_data.next_batch()` is a generator that generates data for both `x` and `y` arguments(I have used this since [`model.fit_generator` is being deprecated](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit_generator) and this generator and almost complete code is partially inspired from [this example from keras ocr examples on GitHub](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/1a3ee8441933fc007be6b2beb47af67998d50737/examples/image_ocr.py#L445), also from which I have used ctc loss function shown below.) }}*

Here is my complete model:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras import backend as tf_keras_backend

def ctc_lambda_func(args):
    y_pred, labels, input_length, label_length = args
    # the 2 is critical here, since the first couple outputs of the RNN tend to be garbage:
    y_pred = y_pred[:, 2:, :]
    return tf_keras_backend.ctc_batch_cost(labels, y_pred, input_length, label_length)

# Make Network
input_data = layers.Input(name='the_input', shape=(128, 64, 1), dtype='float32')  # (None, 128, 64, 1)

# Convolution layer (VGG)
inner = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv1', kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu')(input_data)  # (None, 128, 64, 64)
inner = layers.BatchNormalization()(inner)
inner = layers.Activation('relu')(inner)
inner = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name='max1')(inner)  # (None,64, 32, 64)

inner = layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv2', kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu')(inner)  # (None, 64, 32, 128)
inner = layers.BatchNormalization()(inner)
inner = layers.Activation('relu')(inner)
inner = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name='max2')(inner)  # (None, 32, 16, 128)

inner = layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv3', kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu')(inner)  # (None, 32, 16, 256)
inner = layers.BatchNormalization()(inner)
inner = layers.Activation('relu')(inner)
inner = layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv4', kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu')(inner)  # (None, 32, 16, 256)
inner = layers.BatchNormalization()(inner)
inner = layers.Activation('relu')(inner)
inner = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 2), name='max3')(inner)  # (None, 32, 8, 256)

inner = layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv5', kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='relu')(inner)  # (None, 32, 8, 512)
inner = layers.BatchNormalization()(inner)
inner = layers.Activation('relu')(inner)
inner = layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv6', activation='relu')(inner)  # (None, 32, 8, 512)
inner = layers.BatchNormalization()(inner)
inner = layers.Activation('relu')(inner)
inner = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 2), name='max4')(inner)  # (None, 32, 4, 512)

inner = layers.Conv2D(512, (2, 2), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='con7', activation='relu')(inner)  # (None, 32, 4, 512)
before_reshape = layers.BatchNormalization()(inner)
inner = layers.Activation('relu')(inner)

# CNN to RNN
reshape_op = layers.Reshape(target_shape=((32, 2048)), name='reshape')(before_reshape)  # (None, 32, 2048)
dense_after_reshape = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='dense1')(reshape_op)  # (None, 32, 64)

# RNN layer
gru_1 = layers.GRU(256, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru1')(dense_after_reshape)  # (None, 32, 512)
gru_1b = layers.GRU(256, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru1_b')(dense_after_reshape)
reversed_gru_1b = layers.Lambda(lambda inputTensor: tf_keras_backend.reverse(inputTensor, axes=1)) (gru_1b)

gru1_merged = layers.add([gru_1, reversed_gru_1b])  # (None, 32, 512)
gru1_merged = layers.BatchNormalization()(gru1_merged)

gru_2 = layers.GRU(256, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru2')(gru1_merged)
gru_2b = layers.GRU(256, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='gru2_b')(gru1_merged)
reversed_gru_2b= layers.Lambda(lambda inputTensor: tf_keras_backend.reverse(inputTensor, axes=1)) (gru_2b)

gru2_merged = layers.concatenate([gru_2, reversed_gru_2b])  # (None, 32, 1024)
gru2_merged = layers.BatchNormalization()(gru2_merged)

# transforms RNN output to character activations:
y_pred = layers.Dense(num_classes, kernel_initializer='he_normal',name='dense2', activation='softmax')(gru2_merged) #(None, 32, 80)
y_pred = layers.Activation('softmax', name='softmax')(inner)

labels = layers.Input(name='the_labels', shape=[16], dtype='float32')
input_length = layers.Input(name='input_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')
label_length = layers.Input(name='label_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')

# loss function
loss_out = layers.Lambda(ctc_lambda_func, output_shape=(1,), name='ctc')(
    [y_pred, labels, input_length, label_length]
)

model = Model(inputs=[input_data, labels, input_length, label_length], outputs=loss_out)
```

compiling it:

```
model.compile(loss={'ctc': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred}, optimizer = 'adam')
```

I have also tried to make sure dimensions are correct by debugging in multiple ways, but to no avail.

How do I fix this? Or what have I done incorrectly that led to this error?

**EDIT 1:**
Here is the model summary:
And my batch size is 64.
[image: model summary as image]

Comment: Could you provide model summary?

Comment: @Aditya Mishra, do check my edit now.

Comment: Can you provide the TF version? It's possible that newer TF2.x (e.g. TF2.3) may have fixed some weird bug. It happened to me before that the TF2 keras missed the parameters due to the autograph compilation.

Comment: If that's the case, i am using the version that is and was available on google colab, which i presume is always the latest stable version available. It's 2.2.0 currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a mistake in the generator I had prepared for pre-processing images. It yielded images of 64,64 instead of 128,64. My bad to not have checked it.